# Using a Scanner Loop

Tags: python, loops

I have a file that contains the numbers 11 5 3 51, Im trying to use a scanner to read the file and then print out the smallest number in that file. But for some reason when I run the program below it keeps saying "the smallest number is 7" lol and Im consued as to where the program is even getting the number 7 from? There isnt a number 7 any where in the file or my program for that matter.....What could be the issue?

```
from scanner import*


def main():
    s = Scanner("data.txt")
    items = ("data.txt")
    i = s.readint()
    ismallest = 0
    for i in range(0,len(items),1):
        if (items[i] < items[ismallest]):
            ismallest = i
    print ("the smallest number is", i)

main()
```

Comment: Actually you get the index of the smallest number

Comment: `range(0,len("data.txt"),1)` == `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, your loop gets last item (7) from this list. `"data.txt"` is a string, not a file. Your loop does not do anything useful (it puts index of smallest letter in string `"data.txt"` in `ismallest` but you don't even use that variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with `open` instead of `Scanner`

```
content = [];
with open("input.txt") as f:
  content = f.readline().split()

ismallest = int(content[0])

for i in range(0,len(content),1):
  if (int(content[i]) < ismallest):
    ismallest = int(content[i])

print ("the smallest number is", ismallest)
```

**EDIT:** Ok, I think this should work if you want to use `Scanner`:

```
s = Scanner("data.txt")
items = []
currentInt = s.readint()

while currentInt:
    items.append(currentInt)
    currentInt = s.readint()

ismallest = items[0]

for i in range(0,len(items),1):
  if (items[i]) < ismallest):
    ismallest = items[i]

print ("the smallest number is", ismallest)
```

Comment: The only problem is tomorrow on our Exam my teacher is going to make us use a Scanner or he will give me a 0 for the program

Comment: @FootOfGork ok, sorry. Check out my edit. I think that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you call `for i in range...`. You are reassigning `i` to the `range()`.

I copied your code and added `print i` right after the `for` statement is called, and it prints the following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
('the smallest number is', 7)
```

So it takes no regard of your `i = s.readint()` at the beginning. I would suggest renaming your variable, and your error should go :)

Also, you can just read the file, and split the contents, and print using the `max()` or `min()` built-in functions.